# I don't understand the phrase "Just as . . . so."

Tags: phrases

Here is my example (from an SAT question):

> Just as Ireland has produced many famous writers and the Netherlands an abundance of famous painters, so Finland has provided a large number of famous architects

I don't understand the use of "so" here, could someone please explain what the use of this phrase means? Thanks

Comment: "So" is a conjuntion meaning "in the same way or correspondingly". Look up the dictionary and it's there. The answer is "E".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means:

"In the same way that Ireland has produced...and the Netherlands have produced..., Finland has also..."
or:
"Just like Ireland has..., Finland has also..."

Comment: I see, to confirm, "so" means "also" in this context?

Comment: Yes, just the word "so" pretty much means "also" depending on what is in the first clause e.g. Just like..., Finland has also...